# error in installing Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.6

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins

I am trying to install Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.6 from *http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.6* but I am getting error:

*Unable to read repository at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.6/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.6/content.xml.
No route to host: connect*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works here! maybe you have some kind of network restrictions, like a proxy ...